# Encode array itself of Codable objects to [String: Any]

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization, codable, jsonencoder, encodable

I want to send array of `Codable` objects. So I've created a class which conforms to Codable protocol:

```
class ResultAnswer: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var closed: [Int]?
    var open: String?
    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

When I need to send data to server I create a surveyResults of type `[ResultAnswer]`, it's computed property in my viewModel. I'm using Alamofire so I have to convert my array to `[String: Any]?` type. Here's apiece of code that is responsible for encoding and making post request. It's a part of my viewModel. :

```
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
let data = try encoder.encode(surveyResults)
if let parameters = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] {
    sessionManager.request("someUrl", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseData { response in
        //repsponse processing
    }
}
```

Encoding gives me weird result:

```
(lldb) po surveyResults
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : <ResultAnswer: 0x6000005c1890>
  ▿ 1 : <ResultAnswer: 0x6000005c1c20>

(lldb) po try encoder.encode(surveyResults)
▿ 45 bytes
  - count : 45
  ▿ pointer : 0x00007f95b3098e00
    - pointerValue : 140280930602496
  ▿ bytes : 45 elements
    - 0 : 91
    - 1 : 123
    - 2 : 34
    - 3 : 105
    - 4 : 100
    // and 40 similar elements
```

So as you can guess a try of serializing the data returns `nil`.

```
(lldb) po try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
nil
```

I have no problem with decoding array of codable objects, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with encoding.

Comment: Use JSONDecoder().decode instead

Comment: "Here's apiece of code"  From where?  Showing a few lines of code from an unspecified class won't help others understand what the issue is.  And how do you go from sending data to a server to creating some sort of an object named parameters with `JSONSerialization`?

Comment: What Alamofire function are you passing this to that requires [String: Any]. I didn't think you needed [String: Any] anymore in Alamofire.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I think decoding is intended to decode object of typ `Data` to object of class that conforms to `Decodable` protocol. That's not what I need.

Comment: @ElTomato I've made an edit.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm using Alamofire 4.8.1, because I don't want to use beta.
I'm passing to this to `Alamofire.SessionManager.request(url:method:parameters:encoding:headers:)`